# Bus error when running Android 1.5 emulator on Mac OS X 10.5.6

Tags: android, macos, terminal

I have removed all Input Managers that were added, but it's still happening. Here is the crash report. Any ideas?

```
Process:         emulator [460]
Path:            /usr/local/dev/android/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.5_pre/tools/emulator
Identifier:      emulator
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [275]

Date/Time:       2009-04-20 20:03:44.786 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.6 (9G55)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000010
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   emulator                        0x000667a1 sock_address_init_resolve + 87 (sockets.c:631)

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000008  ebx: 0xbfffcb98  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xbfffcb5c  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0x0085fa90  esp: 0xbfffcb20
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x000667a1   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x19a46b +emulator ??? (???) /usr/local/dev/android/android-sdk-mac_x86-1.5_pre/tools/emulator
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe2db43  dyld 97.1 (???) <100d362e03410f181a34e04e94189ae5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x90003ffd  com.apple.vecLib 3.4.2 (vecLib 3.4.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x900a4000 - 0x904b4fef  libBLAS.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x904b5000 - 0x904ddff7  com.apple.shortcut 1 (1.0) <057783867138902b52bc0941fedb74d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Shortcut.framework/Versions/A/Shortcut
0x904de000 - 0x9052fff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.7.0 (???) <01b690d1f376e400ac873105533e39eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x90530000 - 0x9080aff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 786.11 (786.11) <f06fe5d92d56ac5aa52d1ba182745924> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x9080b000 - 0x90820ffb  com.apple.ImageCapture 5.0.1 (5.0.1) /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x9085b000 - 0x90871fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.0.0 (1.0.0) <ad0aa0252e3323d182e17f50defe56fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x90872000 - 0x908effef  libvMisc.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x908f0000 - 0x908f6fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print 218.0.2 (220.1) <8bf7ef71216376d12fcd5ec17e43742c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x908f7000 - 0x908f8ffc  libffi.dylib ??? (???) <a3b573eb950ca583290f7b2b4c486d09> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
0x908f9000 - 0x90984fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit 1.5.1 (???) <f9f5f0d070e197a832d86751e1d44545> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x91210000 - 0x912d7ff2  com.apple.vImage 3.0 (3.0) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x9155c000 - 0x91589feb  libvDSP.dylib ??? (???) <b232c018ddd040ec4e2c2af632dd497f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x91597000 - 0x9161eff7  libsqlite3.0.dylib ??? (???) <6978bbcca4277d6ae9f042beff643f7d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
0x9161f000 - 0x916bcfe4  com.apple.CFNetwork 422.15.2 (422.15.2) <80851410a5592b7c3b149b2ff849bcc1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x916bd000 - 0x916c4ff7  libCGATS.A.dylib ??? (???) <386dce4b28448fb86e33e06ac466f4d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGATS.A.dylib
0x916c6000 - 0x91720ff7  com.apple.CoreText 2.0.4 (???) <f9a90116ae34a2b0d84e87734766fb3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x91721000 - 0x91725fff  libmathCommon.A.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x91726000 - 0x91741ffb  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <4780e979d35aa5ec2cea22678836cea5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x917fa000 - 0x91805fe7  libCSync.A.dylib ??? (???) <e6aceed359bd228f42bc1246af5919c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
0x9184b000 - 0x918d5fe3  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.4.7 (1.4.7) <d16642ba22c32f67be793ebfbe67ca3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x918d6000 - 0x91969fff  com.apple.ink.framework 101.3 (86) <bf3fa8927b4b8baae92381a976fd2079> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x9197a000 - 0x9197affd  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.4.2 (vecLib 3.4.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9197b000 - 0x91a5cff7  libxml2.2.dylib ??? (???) <306036e0070330e35045650e6d9f0d05> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x91a5d000 - 0x91a9efe7  libRIP.A.dylib ??? (???) <5d0b5af7992e14de017f9a9c7cb05960> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x91ada000 - 0x91e98fea  libLAPACK.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x91e99000 - 0x91fdfff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 2.0.4 (2.0.4) <6a6623d3d1a7292b5c3763dcd108b55f> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x920b5000 - 0x92134ff5  com.apple.SearchKit 1.2.1 (1.2.1) <3140a605db2abf56b237fa156a08b28b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x92135000 - 0x92135fff  com.apple.Carbon 136 (136) <9961570a497d79f13b8ea159826af42d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x9213b000 - 0x92184fef  com.apple.Metadata 10.5.2 (398.25) <e0572f20350523116f23000676122a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x92185000 - 0x921e1ff7  com.apple.htmlrendering 68 (1.1.3) <fe87a9dede38db00e6c8949942c6bd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering
0x921e2000 - 0x921e4fff  com.apple.securityhi 3.0 (30817) <dbe328cd62d603a952a4226342711e8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x9220d000 - 0x92532fe2  com.apple.QuickTime 7.6.0 (1290) <bc0920abbbaad03f5513ac7ffbd30633> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime
0x9266c000 - 0x92676feb  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.2 (3.9.2) <0f2ba6e891d3761212cf5a5e6134d683> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x92677000 - 0x92677ff8  com.apple.ApplicationServices 34 (34) <8f910fa65f01d401ad8d04cc933cf887> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x92678000 - 0x92b49f3e  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <5d283543ac844e7c6fa3440ac56cd265> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x92b87000 - 0x92be4ffb  libstdc++.6.dylib ??? (???) <04b812dcec670daa8b7d2852ab14be60> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x92d47000 - 0x92d5fff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.0 (20.0) <c0d869876af51283a160cd2224a23abf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x92d61000 - 0x92ec8ff3  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <d68880dfb1f8becdbdac6928db1510fb> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x92ec9000 - 0x92f08fef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <3589442575ac77746ae99ecf724f5f87> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x92f09000 - 0x92f15ff9  com.apple.helpdata 1.0.1 (14.2) /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HelpData.framework/Versions/A/HelpData
0x92f16000 - 0x935b6fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.407.2 (???) <3a91d1037afde01d1d8acdf9cd1caa14> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x935b7000 - 0x936efff7  libicucore.A.dylib ??? (???) <18098dcf431603fe47ee027a60006c85> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x93829000 - 0x93858fe3  com.apple.AE 402.3 (402.3) <4cb9ef65cf116d6dd424f0ce98c2d015> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x93859000 - 0x93871fff  com.apple.openscripting 1.2.8 (???) <572c7452d7e740e8948a5ad07a99602b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
0x93872000 - 0x938cbff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x938cc000 - 0x938d0fff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <572a32e46e33be1ec041c5ef5b0341ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x938d1000 - 0x938effff  libresolv.9.dylib ??? (???) <a8018c42930596593ddf27f7c20fe7af> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x93908000 - 0x93ca5fef  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.5.7 (1.5.7) <2fed2dd7565c84a0f0c608d41d4d172c> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x93cd0000 - 0x93cd9fff  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.7.24 (3.7.24) <d3180f9edbd9a5e6f283d6156aa3c602> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x93dde000 - 0x93deeffc  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.4 (1.6.4) <8b7831b5f74a950a56cf2d22a2d436f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x93e01000 - 0x93e01ffc  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.5 (1.5) /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x93fa9000 - 0x94050feb  com.apple.QD 3.11.54 (???) <b743398c24c38e581a86e91744a2ba6e> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x9405d000 - 0x94064fe9  libgcc_s.1.dylib ??? (???) <a9ab135a5f81f6e345527df87f51bfc9> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x94065000 - 0x94089fff  libxslt.1.dylib ??? (???) <0a9778d6368ae668826f446878deb99b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x9408a000 - 0x94107feb  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.1.1 (3.1.1) <f35477a5e23db0fa43233c37da01ae1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x94158000 - 0x94158ffa  com.apple.CoreServices 32 (32) <2fcc8f3bd5bbfc000b476cad8e6a3dd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x9418c000 - 0x94198ffe  libGL.dylib ??? (???) /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x95175000 - 0x951affe7  com.apple.coreui 1.2 (62) /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x951b0000 - 0x951bdfe7  com.apple.opengl 1.5.9 (1.5.9) <7e5048a2677b41098c84045305f42f7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x955e2000 - 0x9560afff  libcups.2.dylib ??? (???) <16bec7c6a004f744804e2281a1b1c094> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x9560b000 - 0x9560dff5  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <8a844202fcd65662bb9ab25f08c45a62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x95856000 - 0x95866fff  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.7.1 (3.7.1) <06d8fc0307314f8ffc16f206ad3dbf44> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x95867000 - 0x9586afff  com.apple.help 1.1 (36) <b507b08e484cb89033e9cf23062d77de> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x9586b000 - 0x9586bff8  com.apple.Cocoa 6.5 (???) <e064f94d969ce25cb7de3cfb980c3249> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x9586c000 - 0x9586cffb  com.apple.installserver.framework 1.0 (8) /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/InstallServer.framework/Versions/A/InstallServer
0x9587d000 - 0x95af8fe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.5.7 (677.22) <8fe77b5d15ecdae1240b4cb604fc6d0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x95b73000 - 0x96371fef  com.apple.AppKit 6.5.6 (949.43) <a3a300499bbe4f1dfebf71d752d01916> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x96372000 - 0x96405ff3  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 3.4 (???) <8c51de0ec3deaef416578cd59df38754> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x96406000 - 0x96425ffa  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <e7eb56555109e23144924cd64aa8daec> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x96426000 - 0x96468fef  com.apple.NavigationServices 3.5.2 (163) <91844980804067b07a0b6124310d3f31> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices
0x96469000 - 0x9654eff3  com.apple.CoreData 100.1 (186) <8e28162ef2288692615b52acc01f8b54> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x965a1000 - 0x965a1ffd  com.apple.Accelerate 1.4.2 (Accelerate 1.4.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x965a2000 - 0x965a9ffe  libbsm.dylib ??? (???) <d25c63378a5029648ffd4b4669be31bf> /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib
0x965aa000 - 0x96675fff  com.apple.ColorSync 4.5.1 (4.5.1) /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x9667c000 - 0x9672cfff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.0.12 (6.0.12) <685cc018c133668d0d3ac6a1cb63cff9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x96733000 - 0x96771ff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <1123b8a48bcbe9cc7aa8dd8e1a214a66> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x96772000 - 0x967feff7  com.apple.LaunchServices 290.3 (290.3) <6f9629f4ed1ba3bb313548e6838b2888> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x96809000 - 0x96840fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.9.2 (1.9.2) <8b26ebf26a009a098484f1ed01ec499c> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x96841000 - 0x96b49fff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.5.4 (???) <3747086ba21ee419708a5cab946c8ba6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x96b7d000 - 0x96d4bff3  com.apple.security 5.0.4 (34102) <55dda7486df4e8e1d61505be16f83a1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x96d60000 - 0x96e40fff  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???) <7b92613fdf804fd9a0a3733a0674c30b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x96e41000 - 0x96f93ff3  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.5.2 (1.5.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x96f94000 - 0x97046ffb  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <69bc2457aa23f12fa7d052601d48fa29> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
0x97047000 - 0x97101fe3  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 226.5 (226.5) <2a135d4fb16f4954290f7b72b4111aa3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x97142000 - 0x9716dfe7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <42d8422dc23a18071869fdf7b5d8fab5> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x972ee000 - 0x972f6fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.2.1 (2.2.1) <75b0c8d8940a8a27816961dddcac8e0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x97389000 - 0x97397ffd  libz.1.dylib ??? (???) <5ddd8539ae2ebfd8e7cc1c57525385c7> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x97398000 - 0x974cbfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.5.5 (476.17) <4a70c8dbb582118e31412c53dc1f407f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x974cc000 - 0x974d1fff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (85) <ea0665f57cd267609466ed8b2b20e893> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x97502000 - 0x9757cff8  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 5.5.3 (245.3) <222dade7b33b99708b8c09d1303f93fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0xfffe8000 - 0xfffebfff  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1780  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: Bus errors often occur on OS X when you would normally get a segmentation fault on other systems. Perhaps there's just a bug in the emulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/586ce0e87d13b702/e568e441fea3843b